# How to install pyqt5 on a virtual machine?

Tags: pyqt5, virtual-machine

I have a google cloud platform virtual machine and I'm trying to run a python code using pyqt5 library.
I managed to install the miniconda distribution and all libraries I need (including pyqt5) but I'm having a problem while executing that code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
```

getting this error :

> ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

After searching in forums, I understood that it's because I may have a virtual machine (through SSH, OS : Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 disco image built on 2019-07-24) without window manager. I then installed the window manager Awesome but I got the same error.
I then tried unhopefully to solve the error by doing:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

as seen in a forum and I got a different error:

> ImportError: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

but I think it's the same core problem.
Does anyone have an idea ?
Thank you for your help and your time !

Comment: try install `libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the same error : "from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: install `libxss-dev`

Comment: ImportError: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: install `libasound2-dev`

Comment: Yes fine I did it and it worked well. Thank you ! (again)

Comment: I'm now getting a new problem : "QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-john924734' qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Could not connect to any X display." I've been looking on forums but I don't get it ... Can I somehow solve it with pyvirtualdisplay ?